# Check if value is not equal to position in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove a class for an element with a data tag that doesn't match value in the current position of the array.

The array has values of [0,2,4,6,8,10] but this changes, so I can't hardcode it. If the slideshow-time is 4 and the current time is 6 show "is-active" class but remove "is-active" class on 4.

```
    if(slideshow[slideshowPosition] == currentTime) {
      $('[data-slideshow-time="' + slideshow[slideshowPosition] + '"]').addClass("is-active");
      $('[data-slideshow-time="' + slideshow.forEach(!slideshow[slideshowPosition]) + '"]').removeClass("is-active");
}

    <div class="slideshow" data-slideshow-audio="audio-default">
<ul class="u-unstyled-list">
    <li data-slideshow-time="0">
        <img src="../img/1-1-slideshow-a.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li data-slideshow-time="2">
        <img src="../img/1-1-slideshow-b.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li data-slideshow-time="4">
        <img src="../img/1-1-slideshow-c.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li data-slideshow-time="6">
        <img src="../img/1-1-slideshow-d.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
    <li data-slideshow-time="8">
        <img src="../img/1-1-slideshow-e.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry only new here. Couldn't find the edit button. Now I have

Answer (score 0):

If there's only ever one slide active at a time, you could simply remove the class from all slides first and afterwards set the class on the intended slide, like so:

```
$('[data-slideshow-time]').removeClass("is-active");
$('[data-slideshow-time="' + slideshow[slideshowPosition] + '"]').addClass("is-active");
```

The way you intended to use `.forEach()` will not work, though. `.forEach()` expects a function for looping over the elements. Furthermore `.forEach()` cannot magically generate the jQuery selectors in the way you expected.

If, for whatever reason, you still want to loop through the others, there are numerous ways to do so:

1. How I believe you intended to use `.forEach()`:

   ```
   // comparing slideshow values
   slideshow.forEach( function( value ) {
     if( value != slideshow[slideshowPosition] ) {
       $('[data-slideshow-time="' + value + '"]').removeClass("is-active");
     }
   } );

   // or, comparing the slideshow indexes
   slideshow.forEach( function( value, index ) {
     if( index != slideshowPosition ) {
       $('[data-slideshow-time="' + value + '"]').removeClass("is-active");
     }
   } );
   ```
2. Using the attribute not equal selector and jQuery's `.each()`:

   ```
   $( '[data-slideshow-time!="' + slideshow[slideshowPosition] + '"]' ).each( function( item ) {
     // item is a DOM element
     $( item ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
   } );
   ```
3. Using jQuery's `.filter()` and chaining it with jQuery's `.each()` (rather inefficient):

   ```
   $( '[data-slideshow-time]' ).filter( function( item ) {
       // jQuery allows you to get data-* attribute values like this
       return $( item ).data( 'slideshow-time' ) != slideshow[slideshowPosition];
   } )
   .each( function( item ) {
       // item is a DOM element
       $( item ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
   } );
   ```

Etc. etc.